# Disable caching for antd Tree

Tags: reactjs, antd

I found this in the documentation of Antd - Tree component.

> The number of treeNodes can be very large, but when enable checkable,
>   it will spend more computing time, so we cached some calculations(e.g.
>   this.treeNodesStates), to avoid double computing.

This note suggests that Tree state is cached. When I add / delete nodes from the Tree, the Tree does not seem to refresh. How should I disable caching or ensure that add / delete of nodes refreshes the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add/delete nodes dynamically. See this codepen http://codepen.io/yesmeck/pen/JEjZmj?editors=001

```
const { Tree } = antd;
const TreeNode = Tree.TreeNode;

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nodes: [
      { title: '1', key: '1' },
      { title: '2', key: '2' },
      { title: '3', key: '3' },
    ]
  };

  handleAdd = () => {
    const node = { title: (+new Date), key: (+new Date) }
    this.setState({ nodes: [...this.state.nodes, node] });
  };

  handleRemove = () => {
    this.setState({ nodes: this.state.nodes.slice(1) });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tree checkable defaultExpandAll>
          {this.state.nodes.map(node => 
            <TreeNode title={node.title} key={node.key} />
          )}
        </Tree>
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add node</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove node</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```